# Single object instance using IServiceCollection.AddSingleton()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Consider the following simplistic appsettings.json:

```
{
  "maintenanceMode": true
}
```

It is loaded inside my Startup.cs / Configure(...) method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    // Load appsettings.json config
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
    _configuration = builder.Build();

    // Apply static dev / production features
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // Other features / settings
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The _configuration is private inside the Startup.cs, it is used to deserialize the content into a structured model **that will provide additonal functionality across the whole webservice lifetime**:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddOptions();

    var runtimeServices = _configuration.Get<RuntimeServices>();

    services.AddSingleton(runtimeServices);
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
public class RuntimeServices {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "maintenanceMode")]
    public bool MaintenanceMode { get; set; }

}
```

Controllers look like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class ApplicationController : Base.Controller {

    private readonly RuntimeServices _services;

    public ApplicationController(IOptions<RuntimeServices> services) : base(services) {
        _services = services.Value;
    }

    // Web-api following ...

}
```

**Now here comes the problem:**

Upon startup right after the appsettings.json has been loaded and deserialized, the RuntimeServices instance holds all the correct information (yes, some of them have been omitted here).

Hashcode inside Startup.cs / ConfigureServices():
[image]

Hashcode inside any controller / api-call:
[image]

The `GetHashCode()` method has not been tampered with.
This results in the configuration originating form appsettings.json not being applied inside controller/api calls, all properties are instanciated with their default values / null.

I was hoping using the `AddSingleton()` method would inject the **very same** instance and reuse it across the app lifetime. Can someone tell me why a new instance of RuntimeServices is being created? And how would I archive my goal in having a **usable instance** of my object inside Startup.cs and still access **the same object instance** inside my controllers?

My go-to solution would be the usual singleton pattern. But I was hoping to solve this using the built-in functionality asp.net core provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this call:

```
services.AddSingleton(runtimeServices);
```

Registers an instance of `RuntimeServices`, it does not configure an `IOptions<RuntimeServices>`. So, when you ask for an `IOptions<RuntimeServices>`, there's none, and you get a new instance with all default values.

You want to either:

1. Keep the `AddSingleton` and use `public ApplicationController(RuntimeServices services)`
2. Remove the `AddSingleton` call and use `services.Configure<RuntimeServices>(_configuration)`

Comment: Thanks, I should have been reading up more on the IOptions interface. I tested your solution and it works as exptected, many thanks for the timely response! Now I feel stupid for creating this thread for over 10 minutes...